# USB device address on Windows

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I'm using `node-serialport` to work with USB devices, however on Windows I can't find out how can I connect to specific device. When I use `list` function there is only one item with COM3 address, however that is present always, even when no other devices are connected. How can I find out what is the USB device address that can be used for setting up communication?

Comment: you might want to look at a different module: https://npmjs.org/package/usb